# Ruby Gem InstallGenerator Could not find generator '<name>:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-generators

I have just tried to make a ruby gem for my css grid system. However I am at the point where when `rails g --help` it show me:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 62748
Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]

General options:
  -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output

Please choose a generator below.

Expected boolean default value for '--markerb'; got :erb (string)
Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--assets'; got true (boolean)
Rails:
  assets
  channel
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  job
  mailer
  migration
  model
  resource
  responders_controller
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  task

ActiveRecord:
  active_record:devise

Devise:
  devise
  devise:controllers
  devise:install
  devise:views

Js:
  js:assets

Mongoid:
  mongoid:devise

Responders:
  responders:install

TestUnit:
  test_unit:generator
  test_unit:plugin

TkdGrid:
  tkd_grid:install
```

When I try and run rails g tkd_grid:install I get this message:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 62839
Expected boolean default value for '--markerb'; got :erb (string)
Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--assets'; got true (boolean)
Could not find generator 'tkd_grid:install'. Maybe you meant 'tkd_grid:install', 'devise:install' or 'responders:install'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

I am trying to inject a require in the application scss or application css file of the rails project. It shows up as a rails generator but doesnt work when I try and install.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi had the same issue, look : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542169/rails-5-could-not-find-generator-rspecinstall#39542170`